# В чем принципиальные различия между пустым проектом клонированным с github/angular-starter и созданным через CLI?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular-cli

На курсах по Angular 2, преподаватель сказал что не любит использовать CLI так как по его мнению, там не так настроен линтер и еще много всяких моментов. Однако, сказал что это все же дело вкуса. Хочу понять в чем разница. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну у вас в вопросе уже половина ответа есть. CLI - это некоторый преднастроенный проект со своими значениями по-умолчанию. С нуля же можно настроить абсолютно как удобно, в том числе и так же как настроено в CLI.

Comment: не поверишь, но CLI линт можно настраивать как хочешь